# Is there a Better Function to Manage Styles?

Tags: programming, front-end

When I work with Word or with LibreOffice, I always use stylesheets and the quick access toolbar (German: Schnellzugriffe): i.e. when the cursor is somewhere, it shows me the name of the template used for the paragraph in which the cursor is located.

I wish a similar functionality in Mma: An indicator-frame which is always visible - it would be best positioned in the line below the Menu, indicated by green HERE in my picture:

[image: proposed location for the stylesheet-selection indicator]

I would suggest that this field always indicates the name of the style applying for the cell of the current cursor position, e.g. "Title", "Chapter", "Text", "Input", .... and whatever style applies to it defined in the stylesheet which is governing the appearance of the notebook ("mouse over").

I wish to be able to click into this field such that a drop-down selection folds out letting me chose from any of the styles available in the stylesheet associated to the notebook. There should be two possible arrangements: Either alphabetically by name or grouped as they are grouped in the stylesheet (I propose to toggle between both of them by space or by the equal sign if the mouse cursor was fixed before by a click into the notebook and after another click into this indicator-field).

Also if I click into my proposed field and enter one or more characters there, the selection below should narrow down and offer only those choices whose names begin with what I have typed there.

**Does Mma have something like this?
Would it be possible to add something of this functionality?** (e.g.by one of the zillion ways to modify the appearance of Mma (i.e. by adding a toolbar or through possibly one of the *.tr files or the like)
**What's the right starting point for such a project?**

I do not mean a palette, which costs extra real estate on my screen and which I have to move out of the way when not used. I look for something using wasted land above my working area (and possibly minimising the gaps between the items shown on my screenshot).

Comment: Try Window -> Toolbar -> Formatting in the menu.  Is this what you need?

Comment: YES! Unfortunately it only shows styles defined in Default.nb, not from the private stylesheet. Also you have to click  to update the stylename. If the style is not defined in Default.nb, the field turns grey. - Unfortunately it opens a new line at the top of the window. The indicator field can be move the toolbar. You can place it almost everywhere, but not in my favourit place. If you put it on the menu bar, it can only be placed to the right of the existing menu items – or it would shade existing menu items and prevent them from being used. But it is better than nothing!

Comment: @Szabolcs: Would it be possible to activate this toolbar by default (including a shifted position to the right end of the menu bar)?

Comment: Go to Option Inspector, select "Global Preferences", search for "toolbar", then set "WindowToolbars" to "EditBar".  This will cause the toolbar to appear by default.  But I don't know if it is possible to change the position.